# Utilizing the simple randomizer module I have written?

Tags: python, class, parsing, module, global-variables

Here is what is inside of my simple randomizer module

```
from random import randint
def randomnumget():
    randomnumber=randint(1,10)
    return randomnumber
```

Then I have my text adventure/small game, which includes code to test what the random number is. (I know its repetitive, which probably means I will need to refactor later)

```
class charactercreator:
    def characterget(self, randomnumber):
        if randomnumber==1:
            print'your hero is dumbledore'
        elif randomnumber==2:
            print 'your hero is ruthless pantheon'
        elif randomnumber ==3:
            print 'your hero is Percy Jackson'
        elif randomnumber==4:
            print 'your hero is hagrid'
        elif randomnumber==5:
            print 'your hero is Ingrid Michaelson, Good luck sonny'
        elif randomnumber==6:
            print 'your hero is The incredible hulk'
        elif randomnumber==7: 
            print 'your hero is captain america'
        elif randomnumber==8:
            print 'your hero is peter pan'
        elif randomnumber==9:
            print 'your hero is catwoman'
        elif randomnumber==10:
            print 'your hero is captain hook'
        else:
            print('how did you even manage to get this output')

numget=charactercreator()
```

How can I effectively utilize my module?

Comment: Oh god the edits make me look like such a schmuck. Thank you elmatrak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like `characterget` should be replaced with a simple dictionary.

```
characterget = {1: 'your hero is dumbledore',
                2: 'your hero is ruthless pantheon', ...}
```

and just use it:

```
print characterget.get(randomnumget(), 
                       'how did you even manage to get this output')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your randomizer code is in `randomizer.py` in the same package (folder with an `__init__.py` file in it)

```
from randomizer import randomnumget
numget = charactercreator()
numget.characterget(randomnumget())
```

I recommend reading the [official documentation on Python modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).